# Why do I get this error when using client.disconnect() to disconnect (using python xmpppy)?

Tags: android, python, google-cloud-messaging, server, xmpppy

I found the discussion here: [How do I disconnect my XMPPPY client object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835548/how-do-i-disconnect-my-xmpppy-client-object) and it concludes with saying that .disconnect() is the right way to do it.

This is the code:

```
while True:
        try:
                client.Process(5)
                if not client.isConnected:
                        client.reconnectAndReauth()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                client.disconnect()
                break;
        flush_queued_messages()
```

and this is the error that I receive when I press ^C

```
msg keys:  [u'message_type', u'from', u'message_id']
DEBUG: socket       got    
DEBUG: socket       got    
DEBUG: socket       got    
^C DEBUG: socket       sent  </stream:stream>
DEBUG: socket       error Socket error while receiving data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xmpp/transports.py", line 146, in receive
    try: received = self._recv(BUFLEN)
SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:1415: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
DEBUG: client       stop  Disconnect detected
DEBUG: socket       error Socket operation failed
```

This server code is from the gcm server implemented using the python sample code at https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

I implemented this because my server stopped receiving messages after a while (SEND is still ok) - I figured I might have too many active connections. It's just that msgs sent to the server are not received consistently. That is another problem that I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: If control+c is pressed, it will terminate his application, therefore the socket will be closed and socket operation will fail.

Comment: Yeah. That I understand. What I don't understand is why does this happen even after i use "client.disconnect()"? 
Isn't this the right way to disconnect?

Comment: Try this [link](https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm)

Comment: I will. thanks. However, i do think that the support and documentatiin for python is so limited that I should just switch ti java :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have shifted to Java for implementing the code. It works fine there. The most probable reason is that the documentation is a mess and the disconnect function is probably not defined well. 
Goes without saying that the creating that library was a good effort either way!